# Escape quotation mark in regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm trying to extract an URL to download by using regular expression but I cannot deal with the quotation marks in the lookbehind and the positive lookahead.

Can you fix it?

Input:`document.getElementsByClassName('mdui-textfield-input')[1].innerHTML`

Output:`"&lt;video&gt;&lt;source src=\"https://drivebutler.drk1.workers.dev/0:/Cartoon%20Collection/Naruto%20Shippuden%20(Complete%20Series%20001-500)%20Naruto%20Shippuuden%20[1080p]%20[HEVC]%20[x265]%20[Batch]%20[pseudo]/Season%2015%20(Episodes%20321-348)/[AnimeRG]%20Naruto%20Shippuden%20-%20338%20[1080p]%20[x265]%20[pseudo].mkv\" type=\"video/mp4\"&gt;&lt;/video&gt;"`

The regex I use to grab the url,

```
(?<=src=\\\").*?(?=\\\")
```

What I've tried,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mdui-textfield-input')[1].innerHTML.match((?<=src=\\\").*?(?=\\\"))[0]
```

But the indication of the console makes me feel that something is wrong.
[image]

[Test it!](https://regexr.com/634d6)

Comment: quotation marks don't need escaping ... do they?

Comment: @Bravo since I don't want to keep in mind whether or not a non-letter character needs escaping, I generally escape them as a principle so far as I don't get any unexpected behavior.

Comment: You should use something like [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) to check your regular expression. Use slashes to enclose regex in JS like that: `.match(/.*/)`. And yes, you don't need to escape quotation marks.

Comment: @MrCoconut I've done already before asking --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqP0a.png

Comment: What is `mdui-textfield-input`? An input or a textarea should have a `.value`. Do not use `.innerHTML` for this.

Comment: Btw, I'm pretty certain that your string does not contain any backslashes. That's just the console output of a string literal (which uses `"` as delimiters at begin and end).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't enclose your regular expression between slashes like this:

```js
.match(/(?<=src=\\\").*?(?=\\\")/)
```

Check how to create regular expressions using **literal notation** in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

If you want to escape a special character you should use single backslash, because now you are escaping one backslash and one quotation mark, so I think you want it to be like this:

```js
.match(/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\")/)
```

But you do not need to escape characters like quotation marks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

... [`/src=\\"(?<url>https?:\/\/[^"]+)"/`](https://regex101.com/r/iBpVlF/1/) ... and always bear in mind how backslashes *"behave"* when having to be written within a string for input reasons and how a system does handle them as part of output values ...

```js
const sample = "&lt;video&gt;&lt;source src=\\\"https://drivebutler.drk1.workers.dev/0:/Cartoon%20Collection/Naruto%20Shippuden%20(Complete%20Series%20001-500)%20Naruto%20Shippuuden%20[1080p]%20[HEVC]%20[x265]%20[Batch]%20[pseudo]/Season%2015%20(Episodes%20321-348)/[AnimeRG]%20Naruto%20Shippuden%20-%20338%20[1080p]%20[x265]%20[pseudo].mkv\" type=\"video/mp4\"&gt;&lt;/video&gt;"

const regXExtractUrl = (/src=\\"(?<url>https?:\/\/[^"]+)"/);

console.log(
  regXExtractUrl.exec(sample)?.groups.url
);
console.log(
  regXExtractUrl.exec("")?.groups.url
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

different escaping ... different regex ...

```js
const sample_A = "&lt;video&gt;&lt;source src=\"https://drivebutler.drk1.workers.dev/0:/Cartoon%20Collection/Naruto%20Shippuden%20(Complete%20Series%20001-500)%20Naruto%20Shippuuden%20[1080p]%20[HEVC]%20[x265]%20[Batch]%20[pseudo]/Season%2015%20(Episodes%20321-348)/[AnimeRG]%20Naruto%20Shippuden%20-%20338%20[1080p]%20[x265]%20[pseudo].mkv\" type=\"video/mp4\"&gt;&lt;/video&gt;"

const sample_B = `&lt;video&gt;&lt;source src="https://drivebutler.drk1.workers.dev/0:/Cartoon%20Collection/Naruto%20Shippuden%20(Complete%20Series%20001-500)%20Naruto%20Shippuuden%20[1080p]%20[HEVC]%20[x265]%20[Batch]%20[pseudo]/Season%2015%20(Episodes%20321-348)/[AnimeRG]%20Naruto%20Shippuden%20-%20338%20[1080p]%20[x265]%20[pseudo].mkv" type="video/mp4"&gt;&lt;/video&gt;`

const regXExtractUrl = (/src="(?<url>https?:\/\/[^"]+)"/);

console.log(
  regXExtractUrl.exec(sample_A)?.groups.url
);
console.log(
  regXExtractUrl.exec(sample_B)?.groups.url
);
console.log(
  regXExtractUrl.exec("")?.groups.url
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by the following

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mdui-textfield-input')[1].innerHTML.match(/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\")/g)[0]
```